# SQLDataSource using a stored procedure to insert

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I am using the code below to allow a client to insert a new question into the table. I am using a details view to allow inserting of data, I have created a stored procedure in my SQL database which should be fired and allow the data to be inserted into the database, any idea behind why the program is not adding the information into the table,

```
    <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" DefaultMode="Insert" 
        AutoGenerateRows="False" DataSourceID="Question" DataKeyNames="questionID">
       <CommandRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" />
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#F1F1F2" />
        <FieldHeaderStyle BackColor="#546E96" BorderColor="#465767" ForeColor="White" />

        <Fields>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="QuestionNo" SortExpression="QuestionNo">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("QuestionNo") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox2" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlAvailableQuestionNumbers"
                        DataTextField="questionno" DataValueField="questionno" Rows="1" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("QuestionNo") %>'
                        Width="75px"></asp:ListBox>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("QuestionNo") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="QuestionType" SortExpression="QuestionType">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("QuestionType") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox3" runat="server" DataSourceID="LinqGetQuestionTypes" DataTextField="name"
                        DataValueField="questionTypeID" Rows="1" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("QuestionType") %>'>
                    </asp:ListBox>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("QuestionType") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="question" SortExpression="question">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("question") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("question") %>' Rows="6"
                        TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("question") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:CommandField ShowInsertButton="True" />
        </Fields>
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#546E96" ForeColor="White" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F1F1F2" />
    </asp:DetailsView>
  <asp:DropShadowExtender ID="DetailsView1_DropShadowExtender" runat="server" 
    Enabled="True" TargetControlID="DetailsView1">
</asp:DropShadowExtender>


    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="Question" runat="server"  
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DBConnectionString %>" 
        InsertCommand="insertNewQuestionSub" InsertCommandType="StoredProcedure" SelectCommand="select 
[QuestionType]
      ,[QuestionNo]
      ,[question]
      from Questions">
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="QuestionType"  Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="QuestionNo" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="question" Type="String" />

        </InsertParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[insertQuestion]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here

    @QuestionType int,
    @QuestionNo int,
    @question nvarchar
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    INSERT INTO Questions (QuestionType,QuestionNo,question)
    VALUES (@QuestionType,@QuestionNo,@question))
END
```

Comment: do you get any errors? in asp.net code or in sql when you try to execute SP manually?

Comment: i get  no errors the code just adds null rows into the table

Comment: do you see the sp executed when you run sql profiler?  I'd strongly recommend putting the SQL query in the code behind.  Many reasons to segregate the display and business logic and it is easier to debug by putting in a break point

Answer (score 0):

looks like insertNewQuestionSub is the proc called in your SQL data source, and the proc as listed from the DB is insertQuestion.  Do you also have insertNewQuestionSub that goes to a different table?  This might be the problem